# Memory getting Eaten up Issue

Tags: powershell, distinguishedname, quest

I am trying to find recursively the groups on folders and their distinguished names (DN) through an extensive structure of directories / subdirectories on a NAS share.

I made code and *it works*, but *it is slow and gobbles up memory* for some reason.

**I am looking for help to understand what I might be doing wrong, or if there is a faster / less memory intensive way to do this.**

- It seems to slow down where it takes each `$acct` and creates the `$acctsQADObject` with `Get-QADObject`.
- I see 8-10 `$acct` per container (directory), and it takes about *5 seconds or more* to process each.
- It seems like each iteration of `$acct` is caching something that it does not release, so each loop of `$acct` you can watch memory *increase by 0.02+ MB*.
- I was popping off the `$acct` from `$accts` and trying to force `$acctsQADObject` to `$null` to try and get some memory to clear.  It does not seem to help at all though. The `$groups` hash is then taken to another function to get the users for each group, but I think that is fine.

**Note:** The `Get-QADObject` was from quest.com, and their forum seems pretty silent, so I was hoping to find help here.

The code I have to date:

```
    $containers = @(Get-Item -Path $Path | ? {$_.psIscontainer})
    $containers += Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | ? {$_.psIscontainer}

    if ($containers -eq $null) {break}
    while ($containers) {
        $container,$containers = $containers
        Write-Output "Container: " $container
        $accts=$null
        $accts=@()
        $accts = @((Get-ACL $container.fullname).Access)
        while ($accts) {
            $acct,$accts = $accts
            $acctsQADObject = $null
            $acctsQADObject = Get-QADObject -PageSize 1000 -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -SizeLimit 0 -Identity ([string]$acct.IdentityReference) 
            if ($acctsQADObject.ObjectClass -contains 'group') {
                $Name = $acctsQADObject.Name
                $DN = $acctsQADObject.DN
                $key = "$($Name)|$($DN)"
                if (!$groups.ContainsKey($key) -and $key -notcontains "Group|Member") {
                    Write-Output "Found first reference to a group: $($DN) assigned to directory $container"
                    $msg += "Found first reference to a group: $($DN) assigned to directory $container `n"
                    $groups.add($key,$DN)
                }
            }                           

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you in an environment where you are locked into the QAD cmdlets? Do you have a 2008R2 server? If you can I would rewriting it with the MS AD cmdlets.

Comment: I added after the while ($accts) loop [System.GC]::Collect(), but memory is still creeping up.

Comment: EBGReen, do you have some code that I could use to replace the while($accts) loop that uses MS AD cmdlet?  I am on 2008R2 and I am not locked into using QAD cmdlet.

Comment: I don't have anything handy right now and I'm a little busy today, but if I get a chance, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Note that import-module ActiveDirectory did not work.  I am not sure yet on how to get this working.  I did get-module and do not see much installed and definitely not Active Directory.  Everything I read seems to indicate it comes with it.  I see for Windows 7 you need to install RSAT, maybe you need this on the 2008 server?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Get-QADGroup` instead of `Get-QADObject`? That way you're guaranteed to get a group. Then you can just pull the DN property from it. I wrote some code that's useful for folder audit stuff that it sounds like you're trying to do. It can be found in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994787/possible-race-condition-in-multi-threaded-folder-acl-audit-powershell-script). To get members of a group, you can use `Get-QADGroupMember $groupname -Indirect`.